# An environment for detailed calculations

Tags: align, environments, comments

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, xcolor, comment}

% \specialcomment{details}{\begingroup\color{gray}}{\endgroup}  % This does not work with aligned
\includecomment{details}
% \excludecomment{details}   % Uncomment to exclude details.

\begin{document}
This is my calculation:
\[\begin{aligned}
    &X = Y\\
\begin{details}
    &=Y_{1} \\ &\leq Y_{2}
\end{details}
    &\le Z
  \end{aligned}\]
\begin{details}
  These are even more details: \[A = B\]
\end{details}
\end{document}
```

I define a `details` environment which I use to enclose detailed calculations that I can selectively hide (by uncommenting the line with `excludecomment`). The previous environment works great even with the `aligned` environment by using the `comment` package. However, I would like to modify the environment so that the details are colored in gray. The most obvious modification (using `specialcomment`) does not work with `aligned`. I assume this is because the cells in an `aligned` environment cannot be broken with groups.

Is there a way to define such an environment while still working with `aligned`?

EDIT: Any solution would be most welcome, even if it does not involve comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the special comment `details` like that, then it works:

```
\specialcomment{details}{%
   \global\everymath{\color{gray}}%
   \global\everydisplay{\color{gray}}%
   \color{gray}%
}{%
   \global\everymath{\normalcolor}%
   \global\everydisplay{\normalcolor}%
   \normalcolor
}
```

The problem is that any definitions within an `aligned` cell are local, unless they are made global. Opening a group in one cell and closing it in another does not work.

Details included:

[image]

Details excluded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, xcolor, comment}
\specialcomment{details}{%
   \global\everymath{\color{gray}}%
   \global\everydisplay{\color{gray}}%
   \color{gray}%
}{%
   \global\everymath{\normalcolor}%
   \global\everydisplay{\normalcolor}%
   \normalcolor
}
%\excludecomment{details}   % Uncomment to exclude details.
\begin{document}
This is my calculation:
\[\begin{aligned}
    &X = Y\\
\begin{details}
    &=Y_{1} \\ &\leq Y_{2}
\end{details}
    &\le Z
  \end{aligned}\]
\begin{details}
  These are even more details: \[A = B\]
\end{details}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Although this seems to break the environment `align` for some reason. I know this wasn't part of the original questions, but I am wondering if there's an easy fix.

Comment: I should add that the solution breaks the `align` environment when details are not excluded and after first use of `details`. Even in `align` environments that do not use `details`.

Comment: I don't think that there is a good solution to your problem the way you try it. My solution works only in some cases. In case you try to do a presentation with overlays and partial uncovering: For this, there is the `beamer` class, which does the things you apparently want.

Comment: And keep the bounty (in case you feel obliged to give it away), my solution is not that great.

Comment: I think it's a good solution. I just need to modify so that `\color{gray}` is added to `everymath` and `everydisplay` instead of replacing the previous value and then the previous value should be restored at the end. Thanks for the help @gernot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution by @gernot, with the fix I mentioned in the comments, which does not break `align` after first use of `details`,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, xcolor, comment}

\makeatletter
\specialcomment{details}{%
  \xdef\@oldeverymath{\the\everymath}%
  \xdef\@oldeverydisplay{\the\everydisplay}%
  \global\everymath\expandafter{\@oldeverymath\color{gray}}%
  \global\everydisplay\expandafter{\@oldeverydisplay\color{gray}}%
  \color{gray}%
}{%
  \global\everymath\expandafter{\@oldeverymath}%
  \global\everydisplay\expandafter{\@oldeverydisplay}%
  \normalcolor%
}
\makeatother
%\excludecomment{details}   % Uncomment to exclude details.
\begin{document}

This is my calculation:
\[\begin{aligned}
    &X = Y\\
\begin{details}
      &=Y_{1} \\ &\leq Y_{2}
\end{details}
    &\le Z
  \end{aligned}\]
\begin{details}
  These are even more details: \[A = B\]
\end{details}

\begin{align}
  A&=B\\
% \begin{details} % Not supported by comment package
%   &=C\\
% \end{details}
  &=D
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, using a `comment` environment inside `align` seems unsupported for some reason, so `details` does not work there for a similar reason.